# How can I tell what modules of the Rust std lib are included by default?

Tags: rust, standard-library

e.g.

If I want stdin() I need:

```
use std::io;
```

If I want to x.cos() where x is, say, a f64:

```
use std::num::FloatMath
```

is not needed.

I found this out by stumbling around. Is there a more formal source for this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the contents of [std::prelude](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html)

Comment: Perfect! and thank you for the quick answer. I'll accept this answer after the timeout period has expired.